# babel v7 upgrade causing unexpected token import in files imported by related path and in plugin-transform-runtime

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader, babel-node

After upgrading to 7 none of the googled answers not working.

[I have a project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGLLC.png)

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn dev:start",
    "restart": "touch src/shared/app.jsx",
    "dev:start": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=dev nodemon -e js,jsx --watch src/server --exec babel-node src/server",
    "dev:wds": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --progress --info-verbosity verbose",
    "prod:build": "rimraf lib dist && babel src -d lib --ignore .test.js  && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --color --display-error-details",
    "prod:start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start lib/server && pm2 logs",
    "prod:stop": "pm2 delete server",
    "lint": "eslint src webpack.config.babel.js --ext .js,.jsx",
    "test": "yarn lint && flow && jest --coverage",
    "precommit": "yarn test",
    "prepush": "yarn test && yarn prod:build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "@gfx/zopfli": "^1.0.10",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-recharts": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.14",
    "babel-plugin-webpack-alias": "^2.1.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^4.22.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "webpack-spritesmith": "^0.4.1"
 }
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": {
          "version": 3,
          "proposals": true
        },
        "debug": true
      }
   ],
   "@babel/preset-flow",
   "@babel/preset-react"
 ],
  "plugins": [
    "lodash",
    "flow-react-proptypes",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "transform-imports",
      {
        "react-router": {
          "transform": "react-router/${member}",
          "preventFullImport": true
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 3,
        "helpers": true,
        "useESModules": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**First** babel doesn't transpile plugin-transform-runtime (or perhaps any file in node_modules)

After `babel-node src/server`
[Got an error Unexpeted token import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WGL.png)

**Second** If i turn off plugin-transform-runtime, everything is fine, until babel meet a 
[relative imported file and import in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI3hB.png)

Every others import constructions don't lead to such errors

[imported file causing error importing in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZiqz.png)

[Error just here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ssOa.png)

Whatever packages i've been installed, whatever config files neither *.babelrc* nor *babel.config.json* - not working, in babel 6 have no problems

Is it rooting or structure issues, or maybe config?
Tried to re-install all packages, clearing cache. Same error

However, `prod:build` aka `babel src -d lib` is working fine, but `webpack` then crushed on same

```
\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs3\helpers\esm\defineProperty.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _Object$defineProperty from "../../core-js/object/define-property";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:172:36)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\webpack.config.babel.js:29:47)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:133:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:135:6)
    at C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at yargs.parse (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:241:39)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:563:18)
    at C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:219:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marat.m\PhpstormProjects\b2b-node\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:538:3)
```

Comment: Ok. Second point is out of case cause of wrong file extension. But first (`npx babel-node node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js` -> unexpected token import) is still here. Any kinds?

Comment: First case gone through not using plugin-transform-runtime with preset-env